# Group of Graphs.

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

Let X be collection of some graph and let # be operation on X where (X, #) is a nontrivial group. Is X exists? If yes, then give some example of (X,#)

Comment: No idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

let V be {v,u} (two points) and $E_0 = \emptyset , E_1 = {v,u}$(a vertex between v and u). lets define $G_0=(V,E_0) , G_1=(V,E_1)$, and X={$G_0,G_1$}.
also # will be the next operator on the graphs from set X :   $G_i $# $G_j = G_{(i+j) \ mod \ 2}$.

we can check by hand that (X,#) is a group but we can also see that (X,#)$\cong (${0,1}$, +_{mod \ 2})$.
also $G_1 \neq G_0$ so it is not trivial.